# Fanless mini PC for Linux

Tags: linux, mini-pc, fanless

I'm looking for small fanless mini PC to install Linux and use it on my desk with the following features:

- Linux compatible,
- Intel i5/i7 or Xeon family (not Atom),
- should be silent (no any fans),
- budget up to £1000/1500USD,
- available to order in EU,
- standard features such as USB, networking, etc.

The more compute power it has (performance), the better.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **IPC2** (Intense PC) mini PC (and similar) which comes with 4th/5th generation of Intel® Core™ i7 Processors and it is compatible with with Linux and Windows.

Please check the product [page at fit-pc.com about IPC2](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/ipc2/).

There is also [**fit-PC4**](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/fit-pc4/) which is based on AMD G-Series APU (3 times the performance of the previous [fit-PC3](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/fit-pc3/)).

It's available in Amazon (UK) or can be ordered directly from the [CompuLab’s website](http://www.fit-pc.com/).

For more details, check also the [Wikipedia fit-PC page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fit-PC).

Comment: 3 times performance of previous fit-pc3 still means crap when you realize pc3 has performance of your router.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am in no way involved with the company I am about to recommend, nor did I ever buy any of their systems. But I was considering to and have read good recensions about them in german IT magazines:

http://www.deltatronic.de/de/willkommen/nur-luefterlos

http://www.deltatronic.de/en/welcome/only-fanless

"no any fans" should be covered as they do not use fans neither on CPU, nor PSU nor the chassis. The configurations offered should be within your budget.

I also offer another link http://www.ichbinleise.de/ - a company I know nothing about, but they seem to offer the same products based on the same design principles.